# NDK Installation with react-native run-android takes so much time

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-ndk

Regarding the above topic, it usually takes this much time to install NDK. I ran the newly created app with react-native run-android command. My virtual device and android studio is also running along with react-native start in another terminal.
Please refer to below.

[image: vscode screenshot]

Comment: do you use fs caching or docker layers, or anything to skip downloading everything and install everything?

Comment: no bro I only use npm . no Yarn or docker. Can you share any fs caching methods? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it'll take time. The NDKs are pretty huge like above 1 GB in size irrespective of the platform.[image]